# Trying to get a varible from another class

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to have my `main` class get the contents of the `alertText` from another class that scrapes a website using `Jsoup`. The scrapping works fine, I'm just having trouble getting the `alertText` variable to not error. I'm trying to have the main class call on the `AlertSystemDaemon` class to fill in the contents of the `JLabel jLabelAlertSystem`. 
I have tried using `jLabelAlertSystem.setText(String.valueOf(alertText));`

but that will jsut error on the `alertText` as before.

**Main Class:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    mainPanel.initialize();
    mainPanel.frame.setVisible(true);
    systemTray();
}


private void initialize() {

    SplashScreen splash = new SplashScreen(3000);
    splash.showSplash();

    AlertSystemDaemon alertsystemdaemonobject = new AlertSystemDaemon();
        try {
            alertsystemdaemonobject.alertSystemMessage();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle(Label.MAIN_PANEL);
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 1140, 768);//
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);


    JLabel jLabelAlertSystem = new JLabel(alertText, SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    jLabelAlertSystem.setBounds(750, 0, 360, 20);
    jLabelAlertSystem.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 15));
    jLabelAlertSystem.setForeground (Color.red);
    jLabelAlertSystem.setText(String.valueOf(alertText));
    frame.getContentPane().add(jLabelAlertSystem);
```

**Other Class:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;


public class AlertSystemDaemon  {

public void alertSystemMessage() throws IOException {
//MainPanel mainpanel = new MainPanel();
 String url = "http://example.com/alertpage";
  Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

  String alertText = document.select("p").first().text();        
//  jLabelAlertSystem.setText(String.valueOf(alertText));
      System.out.println(alertText);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just change your method `public void alertSystemMessage()` to `public String alertSystemMessage()` in the class `AlertSystemDaemon` and instead of `sysout` the `alertText` you return it like this:

```
public String alertSystemMessage() throws IOException {
    String url = "http://example.com/alertpage";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    String alertText = document.select("p").first().text();        
    return alertText;
}
```

Then in the method you call it, create a string variable to hold its value, like this:

```
AlertSystemDaemon alertsystemdaemonobject = new AlertSystemDaemon();
String someNameYouWant = null;
try {
    someNameYouWant = alertsystemdaemonobject.alertSystemMessage();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
//use someNameYouWant at your will.
```

Comment: Thank you so much!